# Intel Pin: function not being analyzed depending on symbols initialization

Tags: c++, x86, linker, elf, intel-pin

While instrumenting some code with Intel Pin I got a strange behavior that I isolated in the code below.

Basically, in the trace of my Pin Tool I noticed that some parts were missing and found that a call to `PIN_InitSymbolsAlt(SYMBOL_INFO_MODE(UINT32(IFUNC_SYMBOLS) | UINT32(DEBUG_OR_EXPORT_SYMBOLS)))` instead of my previous `PIN_InitSymbols` was changing **much** more than symbols being accessible or not — effectively, some routines that were analyzed with zero instructions before were now displaying a positive (and realistic) number of instructions...

In the code below (stripped down version of my program and Pin Tool), I took `memcpy` as example.

This Pin Tool is simply counting the number of instructions per routine:

```
#include "pin.H"

#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

std::map<std::string, uint64_t> routines;

VOID CountPtr(UINT64 *counter)
{
    ++(*counter);
}

VOID Routine(RTN rtn, VOID*)
{
    uint64_t& insn = routines[RTN_Name(rtn)];

    RTN_Open(rtn);
    for (INS ins = RTN_InsHead(rtn); INS_Valid(ins); ins = INS_Next(ins))
    {
        INS_InsertCall(ins, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)CountPtr, IARG_PTR, &insn, IARG_END);
    }
    RTN_Close(rtn);
}

void Fini(INT32, void*)
{
    for (const auto& p : routines)
    {
        std::cout << p.first << " " << p.second << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    PIN_Init(argc, argv);

    // !NOTE: memcpy does NOT get analyzed with only this call instead: PIN_InitSymbols();
    PIN_InitSymbolsAlt(SYMBOL_INFO_MODE(UINT32(IFUNC_SYMBOLS) | UINT32(DEBUG_OR_EXPORT_SYMBOLS)));

    RTN_AddInstrumentFunction(Routine, 0);
    PIN_AddFiniFunction(Fini, 0);

    PIN_StartProgram();
    return 0;
}
```

My test binary is just calling `memcpy` — again, to simplify things:

```
// copy.cc
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdint>

void copy(uint8_t* __restrict dst, uint8_t* __restrict src, std::size_t sz)
{
    memcpy(dst, src, sz);
}

// test.cc
#include <cstdint>

unsigned char a[128];
unsigned char b[128];

void copy(uint8_t* __restrict, uint8_t* __restrict, std::size_t);

int main()
{
    copy(b, a, 128);
    return 0;
}
```

When calling it, it shows:

```
pin -t ./obj-intel64/mytool.so -- /tmp/test | grep memcpy
__memcpy_chk 0
__wmemcpy_chk 0
memcpy 29
memcpy@plt 1
wmemcpy 0
```

And now, if I replace the call to `PIN_InitSymbolsAlt` by `PIN_InitSymbols`, I get...:

```
$ pin -t ./obj-intel64/mytool.so -- /tmp/test | grep memcpy
__wmemcpy_chk 0
memcpy 0
memcpy@plt 1
wmemcpy 0
```

I find this a bit dodgy to be honest. This feature is not greatly documented, and either I am overlooking something, or this has nothing to do with symbols... The analyze of the `memcpy` routine simply didn't return any instructions for some reason.

Any ideas on what happened here, and why? Thanks!

Comment: What version of Pin did you use? What compiler and compiler options did you use to compile `memcpy`?

Comment: @HadiBrais g++ 7.3.0 and Pin 3.7 (latest release). The Pin tool has been compiled with the `makefile.rules` from Pin, the test binary has been compiled with `-O3 -g`.

Comment: Can you check with `PIN_InitSymbolsAlt` but without passing `IFUNC_SYMBOLS`? I think this will behave like `PIN_InitSymbols`. That flag make Pin read the ifunc symbols, which may be the reason for the difference.

Comment: @HadiBrais Indeed, without `IFUNC_SYMBOLS` I don't get the symbol, so this is the one changing things... still, to me, symbols were one thing, routines another. I guess it is related to the fact that RTN, like IMG and unlike INS, in Pin, are being loaded at load time, and not on the fly, but I must admit I am slightly scared now that I could miss part of my analysis!

Comment: I don't understand why you're saying that `PIN_InitSymbolsAlt` with `IFUNC_SYMBOLS` is more accuarate/reliable. Why would `memcpy` be called 29 times? It makes sense that `memcpy@plt` is called once because all calls to `memcpy` has to go indirectly throughput the PLT entry of `memcpy`. So I'm not sure what the `memcpy` symbol actually represents. `memcpy@plt` is the one that represents the function and correctly counts the number of invocations, not `memcpy`.

Comment: Try to dump all the symbols defined in the memcpy binary using `readelf -Ws` and see what each symbol means.

Comment: @HadiBrais I spent a substantial more time looking at it and you're right, `IFUNC_SYMBOLS` does not make it more reliable - effectively, as you said, the numbers don't make sense. I still don't really understand what is the concept of IFUNC in the Pin world - to be continued. Thanks for having looked at it - much appreciated.